# Images display in Android

Tags: android, image

I have list of images. what i want that when user clicks on one of the images then it should appear similar like following picture. user can see big image with blur background, and user can change this image by swiping finger(same like activity change). when user press back button it should be cancel. Is it possible in Android? I hope you understand my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,you must define a customize dialog, and then open it when you want.
you can code for swipe finger or anything else you are looking for.

making and showing custom dialog [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) and as some guidance to you, use image view and you must use gesture detector [here](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html) or [here](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/03/using-gestures-in-androida-simple-example/)

enough ??

Comment: Please guide me little bit more.. show me direction , that how can i do that ... i am new in android but i want to do that....